# How to define and access datalist options for alternate option names

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

When a state name (i.e. California) is selected from the datalist, I want to display the state abbreviation from `option id=` in the results

How do I define and access `options` in `datalist`?

For example, if `California` is selected from the `datalist`, I want to return the result `CA`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInputId");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});

function result() {
  document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = input.value;
 myObj.info.forEach(function(e, z) {
  var q = document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML;
  if (e.properties.id == q) {
    document.getElementById("position").innerHTML = z;
    document.getElementById("width").innerHTML =     myObj.info[z].properties.width;

  }

});
}

myObj = {
  "type":"A",
  "info": [
    { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"Alabama", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
    { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"California", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
    { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"Vermont", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
  ]
}
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="" option="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="result()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
  <option id="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option id="CA">California</option>
  <option id="VT">Vermont</option>
</datalist>

<p>Option ID (State abbreviation):<span id="option"></span></p>
<p>Result:<span id="myResult"></span></p>
<p>Position in object:<span id="position"></span></p>
<p>Width:<span id="width"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.getAttribute('id')` to get the ID from the input field.

Then something like the following:

`document.getElementById('myInput').getElementsByTagName('option')[z].getAttribute('id')`

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myInputId");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.getElementById("myButton").click();
  }
});

function result() {
  document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = input.value;
 myObj.info.forEach(function(e, z) {
  var q = document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML;
  if (e.properties.id == q) {
    document.getElementById("position").innerHTML = z;
    document.getElementById("width").innerHTML =     myObj.info[z].properties.width;

document.getElementById("option").innerHTML = document.getElementById('myInput').getElementsByTagName('option')[z].getAttribute('id');

  }

});
}

myObj = {
  "type":"A",
  "info": [
    { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"Alabama", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
    { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"California", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
    { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"Vermont", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
  ]
}
```

```html
<input list="myInput" id="myInputId" value="" option="">
<button id="myButton" onClick="result()">submit</button>

<datalist id="myInput">
  <option id="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option id="CA">California</option>
  <option id="VT">Vermont</option>
</datalist>

<p>Option ID (State abbreviation):<span id="option"></span></p>
<p>Result:<span id="myResult"></span></p>
<p>Position in object:<span id="position"></span></p>
<p>Width:<span id="width"></span></p>
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I'm a beginner coder so I'm just starting to learn, but this is logical.

Comment: Thanks again. Here's something cool I can do now to display the resulting state abbreviation in the datalist input box, though I don't know if this would be frowned upon: document.getElementById("myInputId").value = document.getElementById('myInput').getElementsByTagName('option')[z].getAttribute('id');

Comment: @logoologist HINT: jQuery would make your life much easier if you're able to include it in your project. https://jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I should get into JQuery soon.

Comment: @logoologist You can replace all your `document.getElementById('something')` with `$('#something')`. Definitely recommend looking into it.

Comment: Yes, that looks cleaner.